# Rails 4: Using locales in a sub-URI app with Passenger/NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rails-routing

I have an app that lives in a sub-URI, `http://myhost/app2`. I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can configure the proper locale routing for this.

I've put this in routes.rb I've tried with both:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '' => redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
  scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root 'index#home'
  end
end
```

as well as:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  prefix = Rails.application.config.relative_url_root
  get "#{prefix}" => redirect("#{prefix}/#{I18n.default_locale}")
  scope "#{prefix}/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root 'index#home'
  end
end
```

In my production.rb file, I have: `config.relative_url_root = "/app2"`

My nginx.conf file (taken from the [Phusion Passenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri)):

```
http {
  ...
  server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/app2(/.*|$) {
      alias /home/dani/app2/public$1;
      passenger_base_uri /app2;
      passenger_app_root /home/dani/app2/;
      passenger_document_root /home/dani/app2/public/;
      passenger_enabled on;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try accessing `http://myhost/app2` in production, I get a Rails error page that says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

My production.log file looks like this with every request I make:

```
I, [2014-09-01T12:22:56.050499 #15230]  INFO -- : Started GET "/app2" for myipaddress at 2014-09-01 12:22:56 -0400
```

I looked at the nginx access.log file and I see the following:

```
[01/Sep/2014:12:26:04 -0400] "GET /app2 HTTP/1.1" 301 91 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
[01/Sep/2014:12:26:04 -0400] "GET /en HTTP/1.1" 404 1351 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

So redirection from `/app2` to `/en` is occurring but `myhost/en` doesn't resolve to anything on this setup, it should be `myhost/app2/en`.
Any advice would be helpful.

**Note:** Everything works fine in development.

Comment: Why are you doing that weird stuff in your routes file?

Comment: looool. Because if I use the default `get '' => redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}"); scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ {root 'index#home'}` I get the same error: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." Removing locales entirely from production makes it all work flawlessly.